# Keeping Track PHP Sessions

Tags: php, session

This is a simple PHP Code:

```
@session_start();
session_destroy();
if (isset($_SESSION['l']))
    echo 'Session set';
else
  echo 'Session unset';

$_SESSION['l'] = 9;
echo ' : ' . $_SESSION['l'];
```

The output of above program will always be
    **Session unset : 9**
since with every run all sessions are destroyed through
    **session_destroy** and new sessions are created.

Now I am commenting **session_destroy :**

```
//session_destroy
```

Now according to the logic chain, if I re-run the script, sessions will not be destroyed now, hence the program should output **Session set : 9**, instead it is still showing **Session unset : 9**. However, running the script again, I am getting the output **Session set : 9**.

My question is why I am getting the **Session unset : 9** on the first-run of script even after commenting **session_destroy**.

Comment: Is `session_start` being called?

Comment: yes, session_start is called at the top of the script

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. The first time you run the script without session_destroy, the session won't be set (it was destroyed). Then on the next load, it is set. Where is the issue here? You are testing if the session is set before setting it. Of course it is not going to be set until after you set it. Session_destroy (on the previous load) actually removes the session from disk on the server and unsets the session cookie. The next load will generate a new session with nothing in it regardless of what was written to the session array after session_destroy on the previous load.

Comment: because you're destroying a session before creating a session

Comment: If you wanted to start up another session to save stuff after session_destroy was called, you should be able to call session_start again to create a new session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is why I am getting the Session unset : 9 on the first-run of script even after commenting session_destroy.

Because you haven't yet set the variable $_SESSION['l'].  The key word here is in your own quote:  "on the first run".

If PHP were omniscient, it might know that you wish to have $_SESSION['l'] set.

But it isn't, so the test fails and your script says "Session Unset".

Now, if you have been navigating around your site with a session set and not destroyed on the other pages, the session *should* still remember $_SESSION['l'] ... unless some other page unset that variable.

So, if you load this page, then navigate about a bit and come back to it, it SHOULD say "Session set".  If it doesn't, then you have a problem with your session mechanism itself.  Check the php.ini value for session.use_only_cookies, and for session.use_trans_sid.  Make sure that if you are blocking cookies you are using SID, and if not, make sure you're getting the cookie from your server.

Also, read the Friendly Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: I think i got it now. session_start will create a new session_file and session_destroy will destroy the session_file but not the session variables on server memory. So after removing session_destroy, when we re-run the script first time, session_start will create a new session file but with empty data or variables. So when this empty session file is loaded in memory the $_SESSION variable will still be empty. With subsequent re-runs new session file will not be created unless it is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

**YOUR QUESTION:**
why I am getting the Session unset : 9 on the first-run of script even after commenting session_destroy.

**because** you have never given a value to `$_SESSION['l']`, hence when you run the code

```
if (isset($_SESSION['l']))
    echo 'Session set';
else
  echo 'Session unset';
```

`isset($SESSION['l'])` always returns *false*

If you use the following code however, you should get the results you expected:

```
@session_start();
$_SESSION['l'] = 9;
session_destroy();
if (isset($_SESSION['l']))
    echo 'Session set';
else
  echo 'Session unset';

$_SESSION['l'] = 9;
echo ' : ' . $_SESSION['l'];
```

Let me know if that helped you @Himanshu Agrawal :)